# Is there even 1 na-type adjective that can't be used as a real noun?

Tags: grammar, na-adjectives

[image]

The passage suggests that **not all na-type adjectives can be used as real nouns** as shown in (b). It doesn't seem to be a case of careless choice of words, since in the 2nd para, the passage uses "some" and in the 3rd para, the passage uses "all", and there is an explicit contrast.

I was wondering why is it that not all na-type adjectives can be used as real nouns. As far as I know, all na-type adjectives can be used as if they are real nouns, like for example, this is grammatical right:

```
特有は確かだ
```

Is there even 1 na-type adjective that can't be used as a real noun as shown in (b) (to prove that passage right) ?

Comment: `特有は確かだ` sounds ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't know that it's ungrammatical *per se*, but it sure doesn't make sense. Could one say 特有があることは確かだ。, that is, without specifying the 特有? Something like "There's something about it", a *je ne sais quoi* sort of meaning?

Comment: To simplify the example, in それは確かだ, "確か" is not a noun. It's an adjective. It just happens to require だ same as a noun. Note that you can't say 確かは or 確かを, except maybe as a "special effect" that's intentionally ungrammatical.

Comment: @Matt hm ok, initially I wanted to put
 the attention on the 特有は side and i used the 確かだ as "filler" but seems like the 確か side is getting the attention.

Comment: @sawa is there a way to form a grammatical sentence starting with 特有は (having 特有 as a "real-noun") ?

Comment: @Parcerier I don't think so.

Comment: @sawa could you recommend me a dictionary that has the part-of-speech properly listed? For example, WWWJDIC lists 特有 as a noun, but I believe it is wrongly listed (many of the entries there are not accurate as well).

Comment: @Pacerier That is not wrong. It is a noun. Just like there are adjectives that cannot be used attributively, there are nouns that cannot be used as an argument. Most Japanese dictionaries are based on traditional 国語学, and is unrelyable from modern point of view.

Comment: @sawa Btw what do you mean when you say traditional 国語学 is unrelyable now
?

Comment: @Pacerier Classifying parts of speech depends on what linguistic theory you rely on. Traditional kokugogaku doesn't even acknowledge na-adjectives as a word. It corresponds to what they call the stem of 形容動詞 (adjectival verb), which in no sense behaves like a verb. Furthurmore, the notion of parts of speech is supposed to be morphological (based on forms) rather than semantic (based on meanings). Nevertheless kokugogaku as well as ordinary Japanese textbooks (not the traditional ones) mix up these notions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are to follow how Japanese dictionaries classify them, we don't have to worry about the fact **"not all na-type adjectives can be used as real nouns"**. The Japanese dictionary lists `健康` as both 名詞 (noun) and 形容動詞 (na-adjective) so that's why it can be used as a noun. On the other hand, `確か` is not listed as noun, therefore it cannot be used as a noun. One more example is `きれい`.

---

Previously I used [dic.yahoo.co.jp](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp) or [dictionary.goo.ne.jp](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp). Now maybe I recommend [Weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/). It also has bidirectional English-Japanese dictionary ([other screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2VoE.png)).
[image: The Sanseid entry for たしか in Weblio]

Comment: This is the problem I have because the only dictionary I have is WWWJDIC and it often has errors in this regards. I was wondering which dictionary do you use?

Comment: @Pacerier okay, answer updated

Answer (score 4):

*Is there even 1 na-type adjective that can't be used as a real noun as shown in (b) (to prove that passage right) ?* : Yes. 確かに一つの答えは確かだ。

Comment: btw is there a special term for these nouns?

Comment: Yes. You can find it here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar

Comment: ok thx for the link =D btw i'm still not sure what is the special class of 形容動詞 that can be used as real nouns called. we couldn't call 健康 a 名詞 could we?

Comment: I'm not a grammarian, so I can't say with any confidence. I suppose it depends on how it functions grammatically in a particular case. I think you're getting a little too hung up on these classifications, though. The real point is to learn the meanings and usages. If the grammar terms help, then use them. If they don't, ignore them. As syokit says, you can check the dictionary to see if a particular 形容動詞 can also function as an independent noun. There's no automatic formula that will tell you which can and which can't. You just have to learn them by rote.

Comment: ok thx for the help =)